# Integration in R using hcubature

Tags: r, integration

```
rho <- 0.2
f1 <- function(X) { 
  x <- X[1] 
  y <- X[2] 
  (pnorm(x-10)-pnorm(y-10))^2*(exp(-((x-10)^2-2*rho*(x-10)*(y-10)+(y-10)^2)/(2*(1-rho^2)))/(2*pi*sqrt(1-rho^2))) 
} 
library(cubature) 
round(hcubature(f1, c(-Inf, -Inf), c(Inf, Inf), tol = 1e-12)$integral, 6)
```

this gave 0, but the correct answer should be 0.1348.
Could anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: What's the value of rho?

Comment: sorry, rho <- 0.2. Thanks.

Comment: Try another function from the same package: `cuhre(f1, 1L, c(-Inf, -Inf), c(Inf, Inf))`. This gives `[1] 0.1347824`.

Comment: But Matlab gives 0.1348, and R using integration function also gives 0.1348. What's the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: How to choose the appropriate function in R for integration? Different functions give different answer.

Comment: My solution in the comment is what MATLAB gives. Those numbers are equal up to round-off error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is common to any numerical integration method:  if you don't evaluate the function in the right places, it will look constant.  Your joint density is centred near `c(10, 10)`, and the `hcubature` function evaluates it mostly near `c(0, 0)` where it is very low, so it looks constant, near 0.  You can see this as follows:

```r
rho <- 0.2

# First, plot the density function

fn <- function(x, y) (pnorm(x-10)-pnorm(y-10))^2*(exp(-((x-10)^2-2*rho*(x-10)*(y-10)+(y-10)^2)/(2*(1-rho^2)))/(2*pi*sqrt(1-rho^2)))

# Record the points used by hcubature

pts <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2)
f1 <- function(X) { 
  pts <<- rbind(pts, X)
  fn(X[1], X[2])
}
library(cubature)
round(hcubature(f1, c(-Inf, -Inf), c(Inf, Inf), tol = 1e-12)$integral, 6)
#> [1] 0

# Draw the points on the plot
plot(pts, type = "p")

# Now show contours of the function
x <- y <- seq(min(pts), max(pts), length.out = 100)
z <- outer(x, y, fn)
contour(x, y, z, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

If you centre the function near 0 instead, it is fine.  Run the above code using

```r
fn <- function(x, y) (pnorm(x)-pnorm(y))^2*(exp(-((x)^2-2*rho*(x)*(y)+(y)^2)/(2*(1-rho^2)))/(2*pi*sqrt(1-rho^2)))
```

and it prints the result as 0.134783.